# iPhone API - Sending electric signals thru audio jack

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

Anyone know if this is allowed by the iPhone's various API's or even if Apple allows this?

Example: Plug something in the audio jack and use it as a "taser" (this is just a hypothetical/proof-of-concept example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. The standard way of "sending electrical signals through the audio jack" is
known as "playing audio", and I'm pretty sure this is possible on the iPhone.

Comment: I wonder how loud you'd have to play audio to "tase" someone?

Comment: @Shaggy: "Popular Duets for Bagpipe and Vuvuzela" would be hard to withstand for long, at any volume.

Comment: Ahh yes, like the Vuvuzela Concerto in B Flat? http://www.buzzfeed.com/ashleytalong/vuvuzela-concerto-in-b-flat-hpz